# matching req.body number without quotes

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following line of code which run when I send {"key":"1234"} to the server.

```
if (
        (req.path === '/start' || req.path === '/start/') &&
        (req.method === 'PUT') && (req.body.key === '1234')
    )
```

However the app I am using sends this content as {"key": 1234} to the server without the quotes around the number and therefore the if statement is getting ignored.

How would I write the if statement above so that req.body.key matches 1234 without the need of the quotes.

Thanks for the help

Comment: if you want to compare it with number, then compare it as a number: `req.body.key === 1234`.

Answer (score 0):

Use two equals signs rather than three in

```
req.body.key == '1234'
```

That will let Javascript convert strings to numbers as it does the comparisons.

Your IDE may whine that you should use three equals signs. Ignore it. You're using two equals signs as intended by the language.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the issue is with how the server accepts the request. However, if it's just a matter of `if` statements, then you either:

- Just leave the single quotes out in the condition `req.body.key === 1234`
- Use `==` instead of `===`, which does not strictly verify the value (including the type) `req.body.key == '1234'`. Though I wouldn't recommend this, as it this leaves room for errors.